# jquery: check if there is at least one .element containing at least one .element2

Tags: jquery

I have been messing for a while with this, can't figure it out.

Shortly i need to check if content in certain page/segment is proper/it has appropriate format.

Conditions

1. there must be at least one element .box
2. each element .box must contain one or more div elements of class .question
3. each .question must contain two or more :radio buttons

This would be ok (don't be confused with rest of elements, it's just real example):

```
<div class="box" type="1">
        <div class="question">
            <div class="answers">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="someName" value="1" /><label>Some Label Here..</label></td>
                        <feedback>Question response 1.<strong>some quoted content in bold</strong></feedback>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="someName" value="1" /><label>Some Label Here..</label></td>
                        <feedback>Question response 1.<strong>some quoted content in bold</strong></feedback>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" type="1">
        <div class="question">
            <div class="answers">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="someName" value="1" /><label>Some Label Here..</label></td>
                        <feedback>Question response 1.<strong>some quoted content in bold</strong></feedback>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="someName" value="1" /><label>Some Label Here..</label></td>
                        <feedback>Question response 1.<strong>some quoted content in bold</strong></feedback>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But this one would fail because in one .question div (last one) it has only one :radio button so it's not valid:

```
<div class="box" type="1">
        <div class="question">
            <div class="answers">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="someName" value="1" /><label>Some Label Here..</label></td>
                        <feedback>Question response 1.<strong>some quoted content in bold</strong></feedback>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="someName" value="1" /><label>Some Label Here..</label></td>
                        <feedback>Question response 1.<strong>some quoted content in bold</strong></feedback>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" type="1">
        <div class="question">
            <div class="answers">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="someName" value="1" /><label>Some Label Here..</label></td>
                        <feedback>Question response 1.<strong>some quoted content in bold</strong></feedback>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Some Label Here..</label></td>
                        <feedback>Question response 1.<strong>some quoted content in bold</strong></feedback>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work for me...:

1. if($('.box').filter(function() { 
   var self = $(this);
   return self.find('.question').length == 1 && self.find('.question :radio').length > 1; 
   }).length > 0)
   {
   alert('NO') 
   } else {
   $('.box:first').fadeIn(1000);
   }
2. and this:

   if ($('.box').length) {
   $('.box').each(function(){
   if ($(".question", this).length) {
   $(".question").each(function(){
   if($(':radio', this).length > 1)
   alert('ok')
   });
   }

   });
   } else {
   alert('!ok');
   };

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $boxes = $('.box'),
    valid = $boxes.length > 0;
if (valid) {
    $boxes.each(function (idx, box) {
        var $box = $(this),
            $qtns = $box.find('.question');
        if ($qtns.length == 0) {
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
        valid = $qtns.filter(function () {
            return $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').length < 2;
        }).length == 0;
        if (!valid) {
            return;
        }
    })
}
alert(valid)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4SbXb/)

Comment: UH :D let me test it :D i thought it can be one SMART jquery chaining line :D

Comment: :( Ok, just delete one <input element and it will not work.. again.. see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4SbXb/

Comment: It should fail if there is only one <input type="radio... and pass if there is more including that other conditions are satisfied too

Comment: @mariotanenbaum see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4SbXb/3 and http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4SbXb/4/ and http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4SbXb/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4SbXb/3/ it should fail and http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4SbXb/4/ should pass :(

Comment: @mariotanenbaum the second should fail because there is a `box` element without any `question`

Comment: please post this as answer

Answer (score 0):

`.filter` should work:

```
$(".box .question").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(":radio").length >= 2;
});
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't pass the case... :(

Comment: How so? What's happening?

Comment: if on one of .question divs i put only one :radio button it still passes as ok.. i tried this way: if($(".box .question").filter(function() { return $(this).find(":radio").length >= 2; }))
   alert('yes');
   else
   alert('no');

Comment: It will alert because something is there, this will return the `.box .question` sections that meet your criteria. What do you need to do next?

Comment: all 3 criteria must be fulfilled... if it fails on 1. or 2. it sould not check further ...